# DB2 9.5 How to get tablespace monitor information?

Tags: db2, monitoring, tablespaces

How can I get information about tablespace in DB2 9.5?

I need to review information about if the `autoresize` option is enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [TBSP_UTILIZATION administrative view - Retrieve table space configuration and utilization information](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.rtn.doc/doc/r0022022.html). See the ["Essential DB2 Health Check"](http://www.db2dean.com/Previous/HealthCheck.html) for a recommendation on how to use it, especially the sections on File System Free Space and DMS Tablespace Free Space.

Example:

```
select substr(tbsp_name,1,10) "Name", tbsp_utilization_percent "Used%", tbsp_free_pages "FreePages", tbsp_usable_Pages "UsablePages", tbsp_used_pages "UsedPages", tbsp_page_top "HWM", tbsp_auto_resize_Enabled "AutoResize 1=Yes", tbsp_increase_size "Increase Size", tbsp_max_size "MaxSizeBytes -1=ulimited", tbsp_last_resize_failed "ResizeFailed 1=Yes", tbsp_page_size "PgSize Bytes"
from SYSIBMADM.TBSP_UTILIZATION
where tbsp_type = 'DMS';
```

Specifically, you are after the tbsp_increase_size field from the SYSIBMADM.TBSP_UTILIZATION table, where tbsp_type = 'DMS' as show in the query above. (The query has a few other things that are helpful in it too.)

Comment: Unfortunately no, it shouldn't.

Comment: So are you after a monitor then? Which monitor? I don't believe there is a "tablespace monitor" in DB2 9.5. Is it the Event Monitor you want? The Health Monitor? Regular DB2 tuning parameters?

Comment: I want to know value of AUTORESIZE for given tablespace.

Comment: I have found this info via ControlCenter. :) But I don't know how to get this via db2cmd.

Comment: Did my edit help any?